# MongoDB work environment

Tags: mongodb, ide, database

I just started using MongoDB and still experimenting with it on the windows CMD.

But this is proving to be hard to read and a bit hard to write in.

Does anyone know of a work environment or maybe some IDE plugin that will allow me to work with MongoDB on it rather than the windows CMD

I did some research and was not able to find anything.

The website for mongo offers good documentation, but nothing about this subject.

Comment: On Windows, I use MongoVue (http://www.mongovue.com/). It's free for two server connections, and very inexpensive for many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [UMongo](http://edgytech.com/umongo/) as GUI for checking the contents of my databases while testing. It is easy to use but lacks some basic features like keyboard navigation (e.g. hitting F5 for reload).

A list of widely-used GUI-style administrative interfaces can be found in the MongoDB documentation at http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/.

Comment: Great thank you. I will look more into, the documentation sound promising.